# Alternating button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make a button that gives a different answer based on if it's pushed or not (as in if the button is pressed once you get 'yes', but if the button is unpressed you get 'no'), but when I run this code all I get is 'yes', how could I fix this problem?

Note: I'm very new to Javascript and Jquery so please explain your answers thoroughly.

```
$('#option1').data('unclicked', false)

$('#option1').click(function() {
    if ($('#option1').data('unclicked', false)) {
        $('#option1').data('clicked', true);
    } else if ($('#option1').data('clicked', true)) {
        $('#option1').data('clicked', false);
    } else {
        alert('ERROR');
    }

    if ($('#option1').data('clicked', true)) {
        alert('yes');
    } else if ($('#option1').data('clicked', false)) {
        alert('no');
    } else {
        alert('ERROR');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statements are *setting* the data attribute, not testing its current value.

```
if ($('#option1').data('clicked', true)) {
```

should be

```
if ($('#option1').data('clicked') === true)  {
// or...
if ($('#option1').data('clicked')) { // same as above
```

You also have two different data attributes, 'clicked' and 'unclicked', which are causing you some confusion -- you're not consistent about which one you (try to) test vs which one you update.  Simplify that to a single attribute.

That's it for bugs.  You're doing some unnecessary work in testing for a third possibility other than "true" and "false" -- it's always going to be one or the other.  It's also not necessary to initialize the data attribute to `false` -- if it's uninitialized it will evaluate as false anyway.

Taking all that together, your code could be reduced to this:

```js
$('#option1').click(function() {
  // 'this' is now the element that was clicked
  $(this).data('clicked', !($(this).data('clicked'))) // set the data attribute to the opposite of its current value.  The "!" means "not"

  if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
    alert('yes');
  } else {
    alert('no');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="option1">Click</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a consistent `data` attribute, e.g. `clicked` only.
2. Use `data(key, value)` to *set* and `data(key)` to *get*.
3. There should not be a third state for a boolean attribute.

This means:

```
$('#option1').data('clicked', false);

$('#option1').click(function () {
    if ($('#option1').data('clicked')) {
        $('#option1').data('clicked', false);
    } else {
        $('#option1').data('clicked', true);
    }

    if ($('#option1').data('clicked')) {
        alert('yes');
    } else {
        alert('no');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So jQuery's data function binds data (key value pair) to an element.
Your issue is that you are adding 'unclicked' with the value false but checking 'clicked' data that doesn't exist.

Here is the correct code:

```
$('#option1').data('unclicked', false);

$('#option1').click(function() {
   if ($(this).data('unclicked')) {
     $(this).data('unclicked', false);
     alert("it was true");
    } else  {
     $(this).data('unclicked', true);
     alert("it was false");
    } 
 });
```

Hope that helped.